# Set the error icon position of the DataGridViewCell

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I change the position of the error icon in `DataGridViewCell`? It always appears to the right, but in some cases it must be to the left of the cell.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Try to concentrate your efforts on a UI where you don't have to scald the user for getting it wrong.  Left or right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.aspx). Notice there is a `Style` attribute. That should help you set the horizontal alignment.

Comment: How does this answer the question posed?

Answer (score 0):

You can influence the position of the error icon by overriding the method [`GetErrorIconBounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.geterroriconbounds(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `DataGridViewCell` class. But in order to use this, you must subclass the `DataGridViewCell` (or one of its subclasses), along with the corresponding column type; and use them in your grid, instead of the standard classes like `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` etc.